# Python - Move files to folders which contain part of the filename

Tags: python

I've tried several iterations of a script but now back to staring at a blank Notepad++

I have 6k folders in the form:

```
Reading Festival 1999
Reading Festival 2000
Reading Festival 2001
Leeds Festival 1999
Leeds Festival 2000
Leeds Festival 2001
Download Festival 2005
Download Festival 2006
...
```

In the same folder I have a long list of files in the form

```
Artist at {Festival Name} by Photographer - UID
```

Where `Artist` is someone who played at the festival, `Photographer` is the person who took it and `UID` is a unique ID

My question is how would I go about looping through the folders, for each, see if a filename contains the name of the folder, if it does, move the file there.

```
import os
rootdir = 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\VF'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for d in dirs:
        for file in files:
            the_file = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            if d in the_file:
                new_loc = subdir + '\\' + d + '\\' + file
                os.rename(the_file, new_loc)
```

I have this code which I believe *should* work but my worry is that it will read through all the images already within folders. How would I avoid this?

Comment: Am I correct that all of your files and folders are at the same level? I'm wondering if you need to use os.walk() at all-- it traverses the tree. Do you need that?

Comment: Nope - I realised this so looking at listdir.... thanks for the nudge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your files and folders are on the same level, you don't need to use `os.walk()` to traverse the directory tree. `os.listdir()` will do instead, as you noted in the comments. One solution would be to get the directory and file lists with `os.listdir()` and find the `new_loc` name in the same way you did before, using `in` instead of regex.

```
folders = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for d in folders:
   for f in files:
      if d in f:
          new_loc = subdir + '\\' + d + '\\' + file
          os.rename(the_file, new_loc)
```

The logic here is about the same as yours, just with a different way of getting your directories and files!

Comment: Thanks - this is in line with my thinking. What's the resource uptake between walk and listdir?

Comment: @pee2pee I'm not 100% sure, but I would assume walk takes more resources since it traverses a tree-- especially if your directory trees are deep

Comment: You could probably modify this to only us `listdir` once-- make a list of `listdir` and then separate it into two lists using `isdir` and `isfile`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding properly, you have a top level directory and when you start this process, everything in it is either an empty directory corresponding to a festival or a file to be moved. I don't think you need to use `os.walk` at all, just iterate through what's in the top level directory.

I'll assume you have two functions defined:

- `def extract_festival(fname)` returning "Reading Festival 1999" or whatever is appropriate
- `def move_file(fname, festival)` to move the file into place. You'll need to check whether the festival's directory exists and if not do whatever's appropriate.

Then you just need something like:

```
for fname in os.listdir(rootdir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(rootdir, fname)): # double check that listdir doesn't give you the full path
        festival = extract_festival(fname)
        move_file(fname, festival)
    # otherwise, it's a directory, so leave it alone
```

I do think that `extract_festival` is a regex. Something like this will handle the "happy" case:

```
def extract_festival(fname):
    match = re.match(".+at(.+[0-9]{4}) by.+")
    return match.group(1)
```

If you fail to match (e.g. if you have a bad file name), `match` will be `None` and you'll have to decide what to do. The `match.group` will throw an error in that case. I'd probably do something like `return match.group(1) if match is not None else match` and then check for `None` up in the for loop (and probably print the filename so I could go fix it by hand).

Comment: The name of the band could have "by" in it.... I've gone through the regex possibilities but because of how each element names themselves, there's no absolute start/end of an artist/event/photographer

Comment: Yeah, you'll match the 'by' in 'Guided by Voices', if I'm thinking about greediness correctly. You'd have to do a second check on the group pulled out by the first regex to make sure it doesn't have another ' by ' in it--I think a lookahead/behind would do it, as long as there's no ' by ' in a festival name. Then you're stuck.

The alternative is to assemble a list of festival names by iterating through `rootdir` once and then checking substring containment. This is probably small enough that it's not too bad.